# UITableView change image on cell select and reset others

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I'd like to change a `UIImage` which is inside a `UITableViewCell` when the user selects the row. Thats now too dificult. I can do this in `didSelectRowAtIndex` just fine. However, and heres the problem, I want the other cells (each `cell` has standard image) to have the standard image again. (If the cells have the standard image again, the selected image should be "marked" (meaning the non-marked image will be replaced by the marked image, which I already have the code for)

See it as a `Checkbox` that you know from `HTML`.

Here is my attempt:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

    //Little flashing animation
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        ;
    }];

    //Mark the selected cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ALog(@"%i", cell.imageView.tag);
    ALog(@"%i", [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] imageView] tag]);

    UIImageView *iconimgView = (UIImageView *)[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:TAG_IMAGEMARKERCELL];
    [iconimgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-answer-marked.png"]];

    //..
}
```

The `UIImageView` is defined here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //Add this to cell only once, not everytime a cell is displayed! (Everyhing goes in here)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:0]; // unlimited number of lines
        [[cell textLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Regular" size:33 / 2]];
        [[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[self colorFromHexString:COLOR_DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR]];
        cell.indentationLevel = cell.indentationLevel + 2;

        //        //Marker image
        imgCell_Marker = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 22, 20, 20)];
        imgCell_Marker.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-answer.png"];
        imgCell_Marker.tag = TAG_IMAGEMARKERCELL;
        ALog(@"%@", imgCell_Marker);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgCell_Marker];
    }

        //..
        return cell;
}
```

Odd thing is, the `UIImageView`s have a predefined `tag` but if I want to get my hands on that in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` its always "0". (the default value of the `tag`)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issues on a number of fronts.

First, the information which determines what image should be displayed should be part of your model. So, when a row is selected, set a flag in your model to say that this item is tagged. At the same time, find the other items that are tagged and untag them. Now, reload the rows that have changed. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, update the requested cells to set the standard or the alternative image based on the tag info from the model.

Second, for your use of `tag` - you are getting mixed up between `imgCell_Marker` and `imageView`. When you do:

```
ALog(@"%i", [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] imageView] tag]);
```

you are querying the default `imageView`, so the `tag` will always be zero. You should be using `viewWithTag:TAG_IMAGEMARKERCELL` to find the actual image view you want.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the ALog. I know get the correct value from the `tag`.

Comment: You need to ensure that the image is always set to the correct value. Currently cell reuse will break your code. You need to rethink your approach and update your data model.

Comment: I solved this issue. So I had to remote the if statement `if(cell == nil)` in my case. (It rebuilds the cell no matter what) And then call `[tableView reloadData]` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Thanks. I hope my vote-up will negate your -1. :)

Answer (score 7):

Use this block of code:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    [tableView reloadData];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
}
```

At first, you set all of your cells to their default condition, and then you change the image of your current cell.

Comment: This did nothing. I even tried it with rewriting the `UIImageView` outside the `if(cell == nil)`.

Comment: If you want to add the image to your cell, create the custom class for UITableViewCell. Than the code will work. Follow this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Solved it with your answer and Wain's. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks awesome answer! I was looking for a way to get the selected cell

Answer (score 0):

From attribute inspector, set accessory as "Check Mark" for your prototypeCell. This would solve your issue. No need to change image or anything. let me know if this is not what you want

Comment: I need to use a custom image. So the build-in CheckMark feature wont do it for me. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

Make you life easy. Use UITableViewCell::selectedBackgroundView to pre set the content for selected cell´s.

Comment: How would that help me? I have to switch the whole view(visible part) from the Cell? Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: You can attached an UIView to the backgroudnView. When didSelectCell is called the backgroundView will shown. This is a good way to let cells have complete different content / layout on selected. An other way is to subclasing UITableViewCell and override the setSelected:animate: method.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: this is perfect in my case, so you probably dont want to use it in your case (or let me explain you why you should when you're in a similar position as me)**

The code would look like that now:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:0]; // unlimited number of lines
    [[cell textLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Regular" size:33 / 2]];
    [[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[self colorFromHexString:COLOR_DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR]];
    cell.indentationLevel = cell.indentationLevel + 2;

    //Marker image
    imgCell_Marker = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 22, 20, 20)];
    imgCell_Marker.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-answer.png"];
    imgCell_Marker.tag = TAG_IMAGEMARKERCELL;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgCell_Marker];

    //.. (more data here, just snipped it)
    return cell;
}
```

Here is why I am using this:

I know that my array from where the data for the `UITableView` comes from is only at top 5 items long. Therefore I can simply delete the if statement in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of my `UITableView`. It wont hurt my app (or waste cpu time) because there is so little to do, no know will know.

*Still, this solution is kinda ugly. But its okay (I guess) in this case*